# xfce4-power-manager - can't disable brightness control

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I want to make my own script to handle brightness. The problem is, regardless of whether I check the box in `xfce4-power-manager`, the former sets up keybindings for the brightness keys that I do not know how to overwrite. If I kill the process, my script works fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Info:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.8.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 31 18:51:30 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`pacman -Q | grep xfce4`:

```
libxfce4ui 4.12.1-2
libxfce4util 4.12.1-1
xfce4-appfinder 4.12.0-4
xfce4-artwork 0.1.1a_git20110420-4
xfce4-battery-plugin 1.1.0-1
xfce4-clipman-plugin 1.4.0-1
xfce4-cpufreq-plugin 1.1.3-1
xfce4-cpugraph-plugin 1.0.5-4
xfce4-datetime-plugin 0.7.0-1
xfce4-dev-tools 4.12.0-1
xfce4-dict 0.7.2-1
xfce4-diskperf-plugin 2.6.0-1
xfce4-eyes-plugin 4.4.5-1
xfce4-fsguard-plugin 1.1.0-1
xfce4-genmon-plugin 3.4.0-3
xfce4-indicator-plugin 2.3.3-2
xfce4-mailwatch-plugin 1.2.0-7
xfce4-mixer 4.11.0-3
xfce4-mount-plugin 0.6.7-4
xfce4-mpc-plugin 0.5.0-1
xfce4-netload-plugin 1.3.0-1
xfce4-notes-plugin 1.8.1-2
xfce4-notifyd 0.3.3-1
xfce4-panel 4.12.1-1
xfce4-power-manager 1.6.0.41.g9daecb5-1
xfce4-screenshooter 1.8.2-3
xfce4-sensors-plugin 1.2.6-3
xfce4-session 4.12.1-4
xfce4-settings 4.12.1-1
xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin 0.5.0-1
xfce4-systemload-plugin 1.2.0-1
xfce4-taskmanager 1.1.0-1
xfce4-terminal 0.8.1-1
xfce4-time-out-plugin 1.0.2-2
xfce4-timer-plugin 1.6.0-4
xfce4-verve-plugin 1.1.0-1
xfce4-wavelan-plugin 0.6.0-1
xfce4-weather-plugin 0.8.8-1
xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin 1.6.0-1
xfce4-xkb-plugin 0.7.1-2
```

Comment: Are your sure in xfce binds the keys and not the hardware itself?

Comment: Are you suggesting my keyboard controller is somehow wired into my sound card?

Comment: You've talked about brightness. Does your soundcard have any brightness?

Comment: Sorry I posted a similar question about volume recently and go confused. Is what you are saying possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **settings** --> **Settings Editor** --> **xfce4-power-manager** --> **handle-brightness-keys** and uncheck it.

EDIT: This also doesn't work. "Volume up" button is fine, but "Volume down" button is still somehow dependent on power manager and unable to set custom shortcut via xfce keyboard shortcuts...

Answer (score 1):

I've set up the following shortcuts in Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts:

[image]

This did not work in the first place because xfce4-power-manager still captured the key and the brightness notification showed up. I had to **log-out and log-in again** to make it work. Now the brightness can be controlled but there is no notification anymore (which I don't mind).